# Is Firefox 5 beta 2 32-bit only?

Tags: firefox

Is Firefox 5 beta 2 32-bit only? I can't seem to find an x64 download.

Comment: Have you got one single reason why you want a 64-bit browser, because I can think of several reasons why it's not only pointless, but undesirable.

Comment: @paradroid, I would like to know your reasons for why you think having an x64 browser would be "undesirable," other than for the flash issues (Flash is an issue with everything though, like certain Linux OSs). (I'm just curious, for my own knowledge). I could definitely see how it is pointless. Having an x64 program only allows the program to be able to utilize more than 3GB (I think is the right number) of RAM, in which a browser will most likely never utilize all of that RAM. The only time I could think of x64 being undesirable is with Windows XP (X64 XP == EPIC FAIL by Microsoft, LOL...).

Comment: @David: As well as what you have mentioned, browser extensions would not be compatible and it would use quite a lot more RAM, and that makes a big difference when you have a few tabs open.  I'd leave x64 browsers for a few years yet, as there is not a single reason to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the latest Firefox (Nightly) from [their server.](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-trunk/)

The file is called firefox-7.0a1.en-US.win64-x86_64.installer.exe

You can find full Firefox files [here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/)

For Firefox 5, Beta 2, I only see one version available from [here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/5.0b2-candidates/build1/win32/).

Beta 3 is not available for Windows as of yet.

I do recommend the nightly build if you want to be on the bleeding-edge. You get the latest features and tests before anyone else, and it will automatically update at start if there are changes. Remember though, there are some bugs you may come across using it (since Nightly is their testing stuff), so if you do find bugs, [report them to the developers!](http://www.mozilla.org/developer/)

> Created most weekdays from the
>   previous day's work, these builds may
>   or may not work. Use them to verify
>   that a bug you're tracking has been
>   fixed.
>
> We make nightly builds for testing
>   only. We write code and post the
>   results right away so people like you
>   can join our testing process and
>   report bugs. You will find bugs, and
>   lots of them. Mozilla might crash on
>   startup. It might delete all your
>   files and cause your computer to burst
>   into flames. Don't bother downloading
>   nightly builds if you're unwilling to
>   put up with problems.

Now since you asked the difference between 32 and 64 bit versions, [here's a little information from Microsoft:](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions)

> The terms 32-bit and 64-bit refer to
>   the way a computer's processor (also
>   called a CPU), handles information.
>   The 64-bit version of Windows handles
>   large amounts of random access memory
>   (RAM) more effectively than a 32-bit
>   system.

With a 32bit version of Firefox though, you should not see any issues since it does not access huge amounts of information at a time from the RAM.

Comment: @Simon, thanks for your answer. I think I want just the "candidate build" (not the nightly) for the latest beta (which I think is 2). So, if I use the link you provided (http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/5.0b2-candidates/build1/win32/en-US/), would that be X64? (It doesn't say whether it's X86 or X64--or both). Thanks.

Comment: Further investigation: this build appears to be X86 (32-bit), so if that's really the only one available, I guess I'll just stick with it for now. No harm running this on a 64-bit machine is there?

Comment: No harm whatsoever. I have no issues on any of my 64bit machines running the 32bit version.

Comment: @DanM i added a little bit about 32bit and 64bit differences for you

Comment: @DanM No problem! Please do note, i found one of the reasons running 64bit may be an issue is that Flash is not available for 64bit browsers. You can however, get the preview of Adobe Flash Players "Square", the 64-bit support http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/square/